# Was the King suppose to expose the death penalty when the court could not?

Tags: halacha, capital-punishment

As the rules of the court were so strict, was the King suppose to execute justice?

In modern times there are cases where say a mob boss orders multiple murders and there are no witnesses. I assume the King would have such people executed?

Answer (score 6):

The king (and the court at times) had special license to kill murderers who were not liable to execution by the court. See Rambam's Mishne Torah [Rotzeach uShmirat Nefesh 2:4-5](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1088918/jewish/Rotzeach-uShmirat-Nefesh-Chapter-Two.htm) (and 2:2 for the cases to whom this applies which include your mob boss)

> **When a Jewish king desires to slay any of these murderers and the like** - who are not liable for execution by the court - by virtue of his regal authority, in order to perfect society, **he has the license**.
>
> Similarly, if the court desires to execute them as a result of a
> immediate fiat, because this was required at the time, they have the
> license to do as they see fit.
>
> If the king did not execute them, nor did the court deem the time as
> such to require strengthening the strictures against murder, it should
> nevertheless have the murderer beaten with severe blows - so that he
> is on the verge of death - and imprisoned, deprived and afflicted with
> all types of discomfort in order to strike fear and awe into the
> hearts of other wicked men, so that this death should not be a
> stumbling block and a snag for them, causing them to say: "Let me
> arrange to have my enemies killed the way so-and-so did, and I will
> not suffer the consequences."